# Android show only part of camera preview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, camera, android-camera

[image: Concept image]

I'm trying to show only part of the image preview in a viewPager in Android, something like this mockup where the light blue would be the entire preview from the camera and the darker square would be the visible part.

Right now I only have been capable of showing the entire preview, what would be the light square, squash in the area of the darker one.

I'm running short of ideas and none of the related answers around solves the problem.
Has someone manage to achieve this king of behavior? If so how?

Comment: Before you ask, I can't cover the image preview with other views, that's not a valid solution for my layout.

Comment: Are you using the original Camera API or Camera2? Are you using SurfaceView or TextureView? 

If you are using a TextureView, you might be able to use a transform using TextureView::setTransform to translate and scale the content.

Comment: Original camera API, SurfaceView, I'll investigate about the TextureView now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cwbowron comment end up been a fitting solution, I'll post it in case it could be useful for someone.

Basically I use `TextureView` to display my camera preview and add `mTextureView.setScaleY(2f);` inside the method `onSurfaceTextureAvailable`

May not be the better solution but so far it solve my problem.